# Implementing click event with updated offset position

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button that when clicked, it changes the default 2 column grid to a single column grid. And Y offset position of the containing elements in the column changes after this click event.

I need to know the updated Y offset position to be able to `scrollTop` to a certain element right after the column grid change but I don't seem to get the code working and not sure if my structure is the right way of refactoring to keep them all sync.

```
var lastTrigger;
var target = $('#' + lastTrigger);

$('button').click(function () {
    $('.row > div').toggleClass('col-xs-6').toggleClass('col-xs-12');
    lastTrigger = $(this).closest('div').attr('id');
    scrollView(updateOffset);
});

function updateOffset() {
     var currentOffset = target.offset().top; 
     return currentOffset;
}

function scrollView() {
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: currentOffset
    }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that your `target` wasn't being updated when you clicked a button, because `lastTrigger` is undefined at the time of the variable being initialized. So when you define `lastTrigger` inside the event listener, nothing happens.

[I created a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mayacoda/qxkwn9v9/3/) that fixed this problem by initializing `target` only after `lastTrigger` has been initialized, and updating the scrollTop accordingly.

```
var lastTrigger;
var target;

$('button').click(function () {
    $('.row > div').toggleClass('col-xs-6').toggleClass('col-xs-12');
    lastTrigger = $(this).closest('div').attr('id');
    scrollView();
});

function updateOffset() {
     target = $('#' + lastTrigger);
     var currentOffset = target.offset().top; 
     return currentOffset;
}

function scrollView() {
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: updateOffset()
    }, 1000);
}
```

I hope that solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks. Here is the fiddle with your suggestion but I'm still not getting the result I want. http://jsfiddle.net/sungsoonz/oumaqgft/14/  If you can help achieve my goal, it will be very much appreciated. e.g. if you click expand button of panel 2, I want the scroll to move to the panel 2 in expand view.

Comment: @SeongLee, it wasn't working because apparently jQuery animate doesn't play nice with CSS transitions. If you add a timeout so you scroll after the transition has finished, it will work. Take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/mayacoda/Lb0ytmkw/1/

Comment: This is perfect! Didn't know CSS transitions would have trouble with jQuery animate function. Thanks very much :)

Comment: This might be helpful for dealing with transitions in the future. Not sure why it's a problem, exactly, but this might be a solution http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/using-jquery-to-detect-when-css3-animations-and-transitions-end

Answer (score 3):

```
$('button').click(function () {
    $('.row > div').toggleClass('col-xs-6').toggleClass('col-xs-12');
    var target = $(this).closest('div');
    scrollView(updateOffset(target));
});

function updateOffset(target) {
     var currentOffset = target.offset().top; 
     return currentOffset;
}

function scrollView(currentOffset) {
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: currentOffset
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: It should be noted that `target` element is the element returned by the `closest` method so the `$('#' + lastTrigger)` call is redundant.

Comment: Thanks but I don't think I'm getting the offset value of the target element after the column toggle is made. Please see my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sungsoonz/oumaqgft/13/   e.g. if you click expand button of panel 2, I want the scroll to move to the panel 2 in expand view.